# How to do an efficient rollback, when using both INNODB and MyISAM tables, within a transaction?

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb, myisam, atomic

I have read the related questions posted here, But what i don't get is what if we have to use both MyISAM and INNODB...in such a case if we have DML's in a transaction INNODB tables will rollback, but how to ensure atomicity in the MyISAM tables ?

Comment: If you need atomic transactions, why you are mixing them in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

MyISAM definitely does not support rollback. If you want to ensure atomicity in MyISAM tables you will have to handle such errors yourself and update your MyISAM tables appropriately.

Comment: Hey @JJ, Thanks for such a quick reply. Thats what i am trying to understand that what are the best possible ways to handle errors while updating/inserting into MyISAM tables so that we can ensure atomic data. Once again thanks for such a quick reply